# jquery UI autocomplete error - Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '103' in [myarray]

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to use jquery-ui to create an autocomplete.

I need to get some tags from a DB, and I'm using this code for doing that:

**autocomplete.php**

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$all_tags = array();

$query = "select keyword from nickwebd_web_res.resources limit 0,10";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db));

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tags = $row['keyword'];
    $row_tags = explode(", ", $tags);
    $all_tags = array_merge($all_tags, $row_tags);
}

$all_tags = array_unique($all_tags);
sort($all_tags);

$encodedData = json_encode($all_tags);

echo json_encode($encodedData);
```

**and from js**:

```
var tagInput = $('#keywords');
tagInput.tagEditor({
            delimiter: ', ',
            autocomplete: {
                source: "autocomplete.php"
            }
});
```

but if I try to type, I get this error:

> jquery.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for
>   '103' in ["background","color","test"]

The autocomplete uses this plugin here: https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/tag-editor/demo.html

what am I doing wrong here?

thanks for any help

Comment: Whats the actual result of `json_encode($encodedData)` ?

Comment: "[\"background\",\"color\",\"test\"]", took from network tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It is probably not the best solution, but it works, and I can live with this as it is for a personal project anyway.

Here's the changes on php file:

```
$encodedData = json_encode($all_tags);
```

in the javascript, I require the php file containing the variable above once, like this:

```
<?php require_once ('autocomplete.php') ?>
```

and then I create a variable like following:

```
var localSource = <?php echo $encodedData ?>;
```

and finally I use this variable as source for my autocomplete:

```
tagInput.tagEditor({
            delimiter: ', ',
            autocomplete: {
                source: localSource,
                position: { collision: 'flip' },
                minLength: 2
            }
        });
```

and everything now works properly.